# Is it possible to render a file with combined CPUs of 4 systems?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I have four servers, each having 16 threads. Is it possible to render a single file using the combined power of 4*16 threads? Basically, I want to know whether different CPUs can render a single file simultaneously.

Comment: You might want to look at Crowdrender: https://www.crowd-render.com They are developing an Add-on for Blender which should allow for exactly what you‘re trying to do.

Comment: The thing is that, I cannot access blender's GUI in my server. I have to run a command from CLI as `blender -b example.blend -o` . If there is still a way to make use of crowd-render.com, It'll surely solve my problem.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use a fifth machine - like a laptop or something - as a master? It would provide the GUI part, the servers would do the number crunching. Crowdrender can kick off the render on slaves without using the master for rendering.

Comment: Other than that, it might be worth contacting them. Could be that there is a possibility for command line rendering somehow.

Comment: I should try contacting them,  @aliasguru . Thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a long render like an interior visualization with lots of indirect light and it takes hours to render it pays off to just split the samples in 4 parts, so if you need 20 000 samples you can just render 5000 on each machine with different render seeds saving them in EXR 32bit full float format. Then you need to combine everything mixing them proportionally - so you would blend each 2 of them with weight of 0.5 and then blend the results together with 0.5 weight as well in Blender's compositing so each of them contribute 1/4th to the result. Obviously if you are rendering animations that will be too much work so you would need to look into automating this with Python, but with animations you can just render different frames on different machines as well. There might be addons for automating this already that I am not aware of, so it is probably a good idea to search for them as well if manually doing this is too much trouble for you.

Comment: Since sampling in Cycles uses a stratified sequence rather than random samples, you may get better results border rendering 1/4th of the image with the full 20k samples on each machine, rather than rendering 4 full images with 5k samples.

Comment: Different render seed will make samples unique for each render. Even if there is a theoretical difference it will not be preceivable in practice. I think it is very safe to disregard this. I use the technique and I have compared combined renders with the same total amount of samples rendered once and it has allways been impossible to tell the difference even comparing them viewed one imediatly after another.

Comment: Thank you @MartinZ . Actually, I have a very little knowledge about Blender. A friend ask me to render a 2 minute video in my server. I should check this technique soon and get back.

Comment: In the case of animation you can just divide the amount of frames equally for each machine. That will require the least effort and will be fastest.

Comment: Really helpful. Not what I want exactly, but, the best technique I knew so far. Thanks. @MartinZ